# Why can't I see my whole background image on mobile?

Tags: css

I have a question about: Why I can't se my whole background image on mobile, but I can on desktop?``

This is my homepage: http://odsgaardklausen.dk/cj/

I don't now, if I have make a mistake?

```
    /* Generelt */
html {
        min-height:100%;
}   
.frontimage{
        background-image: url('img/frontimage.jpg') !important;
        background-position: center center;
        bottom: 0;
        right; 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #464646;
        z-index: -1;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
}
.about-text{
margin:auto;
width:30%;
}
ul{
list-style-type: none;
}
#cj{
width:300px;
height:300px;
margin:auto;
}
#skills {    
    width:100%;
    background-color: #fffaf5;
    padding-top: 48px;
}
.row {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .about-text{
        margin:auto;
        width:80%;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean know by now?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of the background-size: "cover". This means, that your 
background image scale to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to top of your CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {.frontimage{background-attachment: none !important;}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very well on android, but not on Iphone. Do you know what it could be? :)